# Hibernate/Json : how to only fetch a property of a sub-class?

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is an example :

Car class

```
...
private String licensePlate;
...
@ManyToOne
... other annotations
protected Owner owner;
...
```

Owner class

```
...
private String name;
...
@OneToOne
protected Company company;
```

Company class

```
...
private int id;
private String mainBrand;
...
```

When I fetch cars, I get

```
{
   "licensePlate" : "xxx-xxx-xxx",
   "owner" : {
       "id" : 45,
       "name": "Bruford",
       "company" : {
           "id": 74,
           "mainBrand": "theBrand"
       }
   }
}
```

Since the owner-company is a @OneToOne relation, is there any annotation(s) to just obtain :

```
{
   "licensePlate" : "xxx-xxx-xxx",
   "owner" : {
         "mainBrand": "theBrand"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need DTOs for this and I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Car.class)
public interface CarDto {
    String getLicensePlate();
    Owner getOwner();

    @EntityView(Owner.class)
    interface OwnerDto {
        @Mapping("company.mainBrand")
        String getMainBrand();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`CarDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, CarDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<CarDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!